# Mysqli prepared statements without binding parameters

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

How do you use prepared statements without having any parameters to bind, f.ex. an SELECT query for retrieving all columns and rows within an table?

As i understand, prepared statements are good for security and efficiency, but isnt it possible to use it ONLY for either security or efficiency?

I have tried to look up answers on this, but without any luck.

Code (outputs nothing)

```
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$res = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    foreach($row as $val){
       printf($val\n);
       }
    }
```

Comment: If you have no parameters and therefore nothing to bind then it is safe to use `->query()`

Comment: So prepared statements are only used if you have parameters to bind? If so, that would explain when to and not to use prepared statements.

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Thanks, thats good to know.